# AS3 Defining coords for a screenshot?

Tags: actionscript-3, screenshot

I've built a photo booth app for an installation and I need to take a screen shot of the bitmap data with it's frame... I foolishly nested my objects all wrong way too early in the game so taking a picture of just the display object is moot at this juncture, and I dont have time to re-organize everything.

I know the encoder can output stills of the stage, but can that be a defined set of coords? I have an 800x600 region that needs to output, ignoring the rest of the stage.

I am playing with other options as well, but if there is anything that seems obvious, i would greatly appreaciate it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the whole stage as a bitmap data and then use the copypixels method to copy the region you need.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#copyPixels%28%29

Or you can use the draw method of BitmapData class to draw a display object into that bitmap data.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#draw%28%29

Comment: I also need to save this bitmap out locally... Im pretty sure this can be achieved gracefully with PHP, which im not too savvy with...and the latest flash player can save a file directly, using only as3 but I need to avoid seeing a system dialog and automate the whole process. Any other insight into this? thanks much

Comment: I am not aware if you can save a file with the flash player, I know air apps can. To save it with php you can convert the image into a base64 string using PNGEncoder and base64 classes from adobe lib and then using createimagefromstring php function.